# ASE write extxyz question

Tags: atomic-simulation-environment

I'm trying to convert vasp outcar to extxyz using ase read and write. But how can I control what contents to print out from comment line and data columns?

For example, I hope to convert vasp AIMD outcar file (100 frames) to extxyz, with Lattice, Properties, pbc, and energy in comment line, and atom name, xyz coordinate, and velocity in the data columns. In other files, I hope to print out stress, Lattice, free energy, and pbc in comment line, and atom name, xyz coordinate, and fx fy fz in the data columns.

I checked the manual in https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/io/formatoptions.html#extxyz, But I still can't find a way to control the output data in comment line and data column using ase write.

I can perform simple conversion from vasp outcar to extxyz using ase read and write, but that is what I want. I hope to know how I can selectively control which data to print out to comment line and data columns during conversion using ase read and write. Is this even possible? Or is this something I need to write?

Thanks

Comment: +1 but https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/423/5